# Problem passing a list of sObjects from apex to JavaScript

Tags: apex, javascript, sobject, list

In apex I retrieve a list of sObjects and store them in a list. So it looks like this: `public static List<sObject> listOfSobjects {get;set;}`

And then I query for this sobject from the db:

```
listOfSobjects = [SELECT Id, Value1, Value2, (SELECT Id FROM sObject2) FROM Sobject WHERE Status__c != 'Rejected'];
```

So then I try to access this in JavaScript and assign it to a JavaScript object but I get an error. Even console.log gives me an error `console.log({!listOfSobjects});`

The error looks like this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: a0H3B000000EWilUAG is not defined`

Also in `sources` of the inspector that line of code looks like this `console.log([a0H3B000000EWilUAG]);`

Any ideas why I am getting an error in the console.log and also how to assign this list to a javascript object? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arthlete, If you want to use apex data type in javascript then that could be achieved by serializing the data that you want in javascript and then deserializing in javascript like as below.
In Apex:

```
public String serializedList {get;set;}

serializedList = JSON.serialize(listOfSobjects );
```

Now in javascript you need to use below code:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{!serializedList }');
```

Now from data you would be able to access data you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Basically this method gives you JSON representation of your data in String format. After getting all listOfSobjects you need to call this method and assign returned string in another string type of variable which you could use in vf page.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! Why do I need to serialize it. Why will it not work without converting it to a json string? @KiranMachhewar

Comment: In that way it will call it's toString version which does not give output in json string.